# Can't read XML file in my iOS app

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I can't seem to get my code to work. I have included a "sample.xml" file in my Xcode project folder. However, I keep getting an error saying:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available."

I'm also using a third party library to parse my XML file.

```
let xmlPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "xml")!

let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: xmlPath)

if let parser = XMLParser(data: data) {
    let element = parser.rootElement["root"]
    print(element)

}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Are you sure your "sample.xml" file is selected for your app's target in Xcode so it is being bundled with the app?

Comment: The second line is causing the error. "let data..."" & yes I'm sure.

Comment: You must not because `xmlPath` appears to be `nil` which is why you get the error on the 2nd line.

Comment: I dragged the file into Xcode and it says to add it my app target. And "copy items if needed" are both selected.

Comment: Use the debugger on the code you posted. Look at the value of `xmlPath`. Is it `nil`? If so, you haven't added the file to your project properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your resource(`xml` file) is present in the `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phases`. If not then go ahead and add the missing resources by clicking `+` at the bottom. If that is not the problem then check your xml file if it is in proper `xml` format.

Comment: I've done it all and it's still not reading; here's what my screen looks like: http://imgbox.com/9GTM1GpS

Comment: Can you show me the target membership of your text file? And how did you add this txt file to your project?

Comment: I added the file by dragging it and the window prompt asked me to copy items if needed, and selected the project as my target.